# Issue when come back from one page with horizontal orientation to another page with vertical

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, screen-orientation

Firstly showing **MainPage**, then I click on button and call **SecondPage**. Everthing looks fine, but when I click on back button(and orientation of display should be in portrait orientation however I get some strange behavior like portrait orientation with landscape(horizontal) view.

**Page1**(right vertical orientation) -> **Page2**(right horizontal orientation) ->(**back button action**) -> **Page1**(wrong vertical orientation).

```
   when firstly showing                         when click back button
```

[image] [image]

**MainPage:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var fullScreenVideoPage = new SecondPage();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(fullScreenVideoPage, false);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(fullScreenVideoPage);
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "preventLandScape");
        }
    }
```

**XAML** (MainPage):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="Black">
      <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="icon.png"               
                   WidthRequest="150"
                   HeightRequest="150"
                   HorizontalOptions ="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"  />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>     
            </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**SecondPage:**

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SecondPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "showLandscapeOrientation");
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "showPortraitOrientation");
        }

        async void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MainPage()));
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity:**

```
[Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());
            //allowing the device to change the screen orientation based on the rotation
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SecondPage>(this, "showLandscapeOrientation", sender =>
            {
                RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
            });

            //during page close setting back to portrait
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SecondPage>(this, "preventLandScape", sender =>
            {
                RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "showPortraitOrientation", sender =>
            {
                RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you subscribed `showPortraitOrientation` for `MainPage` but you called `preventLandScape` from your `MainPage`.

So you can modify the code in `OnAppearing()` of `MainPage` like this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "showPortraitOrientation");
}
```

Additional problem is that you may need to redraw the layout when change back from landscape to portrait screen. For Android platform, you can for example code like this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "showPortraitOrientation");

    //force redraw
    this.InvalidateMeasure();
}

protected override void InvalidateMeasure()
{
    Task.Delay(200).Wait();
    base.InvalidateMeasure();
}
```